# TeXstudio, disable horizontal scrolling for "Fit to Text Width"

Tags: texstudio

Does anyone know why disabling horizontal scrolling for "Fit to Text Width" with TeXstudio doesn't work (one finds this option at Preferences under Internal PDF Viewer after selecting the scale option to "Fit to Text Width")

Comment: Because it's a [bug](https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/bugs/1380/).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because bug is now fixed.

Comment: Well, as of now, this feature does not seem to be available.